# What are the security risks if we allow the user to login on the paypal review page?

Tags: magento-1, paypal, security, paypal-express

I want some *expert opinions* on the requirement/customization as following(I am my self personally do not want this to implement this, but need suggestion so that I can explain in a better manner to someone non technical or ordinary user)

"suppose I customize to  allow the user on the paypal express checkout review page to login what can be the abnormal behaviour of the system and security risks associated with this. "

AS I know that the payment process is already in the middle and allow a user to login in this stage in not correct technically.

Please suggest.

[image]

Comment: Are all the elements on the page secure? https?

Comment: @sr_magento no this page is not secure.

Comment: Logging in via the PayPal Express payment option defeats the whole purpose of the the Express option. What is the main purpose of allowing logins at this point?

Comment: Okay well there is your security risk. Anytime a person is entering sensitive / personal information the page should be encrypted. In terms of what you are trying to achieve I do not fully understand but definitely encrypt the page.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to simplify checkout process by keeping your customers on your website you should try to implement "Log in With PayPal" feature.

**PayPal user Agreement says that customer looses their Protection and that is not something you should force customer's to do**:

```
8.1 Protection for Unauthorized Transactions and Errors. When an Unauthorized Transaction or an Error occurs in your Account, PayPal will cover you for the full amount of every eligible Unauthorized Transaction or Error so long as you follow the procedures discussed below.

An Unauthorized Transaction occurs when a payment is sent from your Account that you did not authorize and that did not benefit you. For example, if someone steals your password, uses the password to access your Account, and sends a payment from your Account, an Unauthorized Transaction has occurred. If you give someone access to your Account (by giving them your login information) and they conduct transactions without your knowledge or permission, you are responsible for any resulting use.
```

You may look into "13.11 Password Security" too